# Access Prop Type passed to function MERN Stack

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm currently passing my resetPassword variable through the updateUserPassword function using prop types. The function then checks the response message from the api route that I have setup and changes the boolean value of resetPassword.isMatched.

The issue is that I can't seem to get access to the updated isMatched value on submit. How would I output the true or false value of the isMatched variable?

The updateUserPassword function successfully sets the resetPassword.isMatched to either true or false dependent on the res.data.msg I just can't access it within my initial component.

```
//*** Onsubmit that passes the prop types to updateUserPassword ***//
onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();

   const resetPassword = {
     email: this.username,
     password: this.state.password,
     password2: this.state.password2,
     isMatched: false
   };

   this.props.updateUserPassword(resetPassword);

};


//*** Passing prop types to as function ***//

ResetPassword.propTypes = {
  updateUserPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};


//*** @route POST api/users/resetPassword ***//

router.post("/resetpassword", (req, res) => {

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {

   if (!user) {

     return res.status(400).json({ email: "User does not exist" });

   } else {

     const updPassword = req.body.password;

     // Check password
     bcrypt.compare(updPassword, user.password).then(isMatch => {

       if (isMatch) {
         res.status(200).send({
           msg: 'passwords match',
           isMatched: true
         })
       } else {
         // Hash password before saving in database
         bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
           bcrypt.hash(resetPassword, salt, (err, hash) => {
             if (err) throw err;
             user.password = hash;
             user
               .save()
               .then(user => res.json(user))
               .catch(err => console.log(err));
           });
         });
       }
      });
    }
  });

});


//*** Reset User Password function that accepts resetPassword ***//

export const updateUserPassword = (resetPassword) => dispatch => {
axios
.post("/api/users/resetpassword", resetPassword)
.then(res => {
  if (res.data.msg === 'passwords match') {

    resetPassword.isMatched = true;

  } else {

    resetPassword.isMatched = false;

  }
})
.catch(err =>
  dispatch({
    type: GET_ERRORS,
    payload: err.response.data
  })
);
};
```

Comment: Where do you need to render the `isMatched` value? You already defined in the `onSubmit` function, I think should define the `resetPassword` object in a `state` to be able to access in whole component.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos Yeah, I've defined it in my onsubmit function and then it passes to my updateUserPassword function to change the value of that variable based on the json response message and then I want to be able to access it in the same file that my onsubmit is in.